# React-Bootstrap stopped working overnight

Tags: css, reactjs, nav, react-bootstrap

sorry for the strange nature of this question however I was alerted to an issue and I can not find what has happened.

Overnight (04/02/2018) the styling of my react web application seemed to completely break. The nav bar no longer displays and the container alignment is no longer working, nor is the responsive aspect of the application. No code has changed during this time, and I can not see any errors when debugging or checking the console in IE,Chrome and FireFox.

Has this happened to anyone else? I have attempted to update the version of bootstrap the react app is using but this has not changed anything regarding this issue.

Comment: are you writing this from the future?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, fixed the date.

Comment: do you have the code in a file or is it a link of the website of angular?

Comment: Have the same problem :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48617286/bootstrap-stopped-working-with-react

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because now the latest bootstrap refers to v4 in the link https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css

You need to change your link to https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css where you have been including stylesheet most probably /public/index.html or just search through files where you are importing bootstrap from cdn and change it to version 3(3.3.7 in my case),  because react-bootstrap(Navs, NavItems or any other components ) uses bootstrap v3 css

Comment: You are a star, this is exactly what it was and I'm ashamed to say I didn't notice this earlier! This fixed it, after spending a morning scratching my head!

Answer (score 1):

Change this:  ]

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

to not lastes version, for ex.

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```